# bootstrap datatable custom dropdown filters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I'm using bootstrap datatables in codeigniter project in footer i included this datatables js and initialized like

```
$('.datatable').dataTable({
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
            }
        } );
```

Now i want custom filters in required list page on required column
 i tried as

```
<select id="s" name="s">
<option value="1">Hyd</option>
<option value="2">Warangal</option>
</select>
```

and js as

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#s').change( function() {
        //alert($(this).val());
oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), 2 );
} );
});
</script>
```

I want to filter using drop downlist for city.

Answer (score 10):

Hope this is what you looking for, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ratan_Paul/5Lj6peof/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table =  $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#dropdown1').on('change', function () {
        table.columns(1).search( this.value ).draw();
    } );
    $('#dropdown2').on('change', function () {
        table.columns(2).search( this.value ).draw();
    } );
});
```

Peace!

Comment: this is working for me 
var table = jQuery('#example').DataTable();
    jQuery('#role_filter').on( 'change', function () {
      table.search( this.value ).draw();
    });

Comment: I saw your post. It's working on the selected option's text(),but it is not working when I'm trying to search based on options value. Could you please help me with that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way :

```
       $('.datatable').dataTable({
       "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
       "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
       "oLanguage": {
           "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
       },
       initComplete: function() {
           this.api().columns().every(function() {
               $('#s').change(function() {

                   var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                       $(this).val()
                   );

                   column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
               });
           });
       }

   });
```

[Source](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html)

Comment: DataTables warning (table id = 'DataTables_Table_0'): Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

To retrieve the DataTables object for this table, pass no arguments or see the docs for bRetrieve and bDestroy

Comment: datatable  js is initialized in footer of every page

Comment: did you initialize once or not ?

Comment: already initialized like   $('.datatable').dataTable({
       "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span12'i><'span12 center'p>>",
       "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
       "oLanguage": {
           "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
       },

Comment: initialize with my code, you cant initialize twice.